# Password in shell

Tags: command-line

I haven't used the shell in years. I went in to do a clean. When I tried to enter my password, I got no sign that it had been entered -- no asterisks, dots, anything. Then it rejected the log-on. What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

No characters (asterisks, hashes, dots, anything) are displayed when you type in the password, no matter how many characters you type in.

You might have accidentally mis-typed the password.  This happens from time to time.